# Comparing types including base types in C#

Tags: c#, types, comparison

If I catch exception, it catches type and its base types too:

```
try
{
    throw new EndpointNotFoundException(...);
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    // EndpointNotFoundException is caught (inherits from CommunicationException)
}
```

But how can I compare types in the same manner?

```
var e = new EndpointNotFoundException(...);
if (e.GetType() == typeof(CommunicationException)) // is not true
{

}
```

I know I can watch `Type.BaseType`, but is not there easiest way how to match types including its base type tree?

Comment: @Augusto No, that is for Type vs Type comparison. Here he is speaking of instance vs type comparison. But there are surely tens of other questions about the is/as operators.

Comment: @xanatos yes, you are right ;) although the accepted answer talks about the is and as operator, the question is not the same

Comment: Exactly. :-) I was searching, really...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do:

```
if (e is CommunicationException)
```

[is operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.